# How do Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVEs) work?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, cve

The **[Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE) system](https://cve.mitre.org/)** is a dictionary of publicly known information security vulnerabilities and exposures in publicly released software packages.

I am looking for a canonical answer to the following questions:

- How do CVEs work?
- How do you find a CVE related to a particular product?
- Where can I find a hotfix for a CVE?
- Do all listed CVEs have hotfixes?
- What do I do if I can't find a hotfix for a listed CVE?

I have run a google search to identify, collect and view CVEs for different products. The results vary however, and I was hoping we would be able to use my question as a basis from which users can become aware of the CVE system, and can following a step-by-step procedure for identifying and collecting product CVEs.

Comment: This is hardly a complete answer, but http://www.cvedetails.com/ is an awesome resource for searching CVEs.

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggests it, CVE are divided to two categories: **Vulnerabilities** and **Exposures** both are mainly errors in a given software code or its configuration that respectively may allow an attacker to -for example- gain a privilege escalation (running a code as root on a user level environment) or to gain an indirect access to a system/network.

Before trying (at least) to adresse your points, its important to keep in mind that the very first stage of creating a CVE is discovering and disclosing a vulnerability. And for the sake of simplicity :

- ***How do CVEs work?***: Once a vulnerability is discovered and disclosed, CVE Numbering Authorities ([CNA](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/cna.html)) assigns this vulnerability a CVE ID then post the CVE on the [CVE List](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/)
- ***How do you find a CVE related to a particular product?***: There are many repositories around, like the one suggested by @bonsaiviking, you can use https://cve.mitre.org/, https://www.cvedetails.com/ or https://nvd.nist.gov/...
- ***Where can I find a hotfix for a CVE?***: Generally hot fixes are updates pushed by affected software vendors, this why its important to keep its Os, Softwares, Web browsers updated.
- ***Do all listed CVEs have hotfixes?*** To make it simple, the answer is **NO**, researchers and bug hunters usually respect what is called  *Vulnerability Disclosure Policy*, to make it simple, a typical disclose starts by contacting the affected vendor and making it aware of the found vulnerability, by providing it a Proof of Concept for example and technical details, the vendor should correct the concerned vulnerability within **90 days**  passing this deadline, the vulnerability could be disclosed, **IF** t this happens, then the "bug" is assigned a CVE.
- ***What do I do if I can't find a hotfix for a listed CVE?*** In general, nothing except waiting an update from the vendor or avoiding the use of the affected software.

The answer was not exhaustive but hope it helped !